# Problem in the command "npm start" Failed at the fourth-tic-tac-toe@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! react-scripts: not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am making a basic tic tac toe game in react. first I create the app with these command's

> npx create-react-app my-app 
>   cd my-app 
>   npm start

In the beginning it's working is fine but when I installed some dependencies and again start the app with the command **npm start**,
give me error

```
shivam@shivam:~/Documents/Projects/React/fourth-tic-tac-toe$ npm start

> fourth-tic-tac-toe@0.1.0 start /home/shivam/Documents/Projects/React/fourth-tic-tac-toe
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fourth-tic-tac-toe@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fourth-tic-tac-toe@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shivam/.npm/_logs/2020-04-25T10_03_35_243Z-debug.log
```

My **package.json** file is here

```
{
  "name": "fourth-tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-toastify": "^5.5.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

> and npm version **5.6.0**

I installed all the with the command **npm install dependency-name** 
and only one dependency with **npm install --save bootstrap** 
**After this installation when I tried to start app give me error**

Comment: Have you tried run `npm install` ? not `npm install <package -name>`

Comment: sir i tried and it work , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. install new version of node

   ```
   npm install -g npm@latest
   ```
2. Go in your app directory and use this command

   ```
   npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
   ```

It has worked for me.